# Issue with another version of Python pip3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.8

I installed alernative version of python (3.8.10) from source, i needed it to use in virtual environment. But when i use pip3

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip3
```

it says

```
/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named pip3
```

also

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip #works perfectly fine
```

same goes with /usr/local/bin/python3.8

how to fix it? (btw, just using pip3 from console works fine)

Comment: There's nothing to fix, the module is called 'pip'.

Comment: Yes, but when i try to install some packages it trying to install the wrong version of it (for python-2.x)

Answer (score 1):

It's either

```
pip3 install packages
```

because **the script** is named `pip3`; or

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip install packages
```

as the **package** to run with `python -m` is called `pip`. But not both, so **it's not**

```
python3 -m pip3 install packages
```

as **there is no package `pip3`**.

Also try

```
/usr/local/bin/pip3 install
```

If it's what you want put `/usr/local/bin/` in front of your `$PATH` and you can run the script with just `pip3`.

Comment: Please try to use **triple back ticks** for formatting code blocks rather than **newline + tab** as that way you can also provide language name for the syntax highligher.

Answer (score -3):

You can try with this only inside your virtualenv.

> pip install package_name

Comment: Please read the last line of the question. It clearly says that *just using `pip` from command line works fine*, so that is not his question.